# Visual Studio Windows Form "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

In `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017` when I create a `Windows Form` in my `solution` I get the following error page right away (instead of the designer page):
[image]

The stack trace is:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.CodeModel.CSharpCodeModelService.GetTypeSymbolFromFullName(String fullName, Compilation compilation)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.RootCodeModel.DotNetNameFromLanguageSpecific(String languageName)
at EnvDTE80.CodeModel2.DotNetNameFromLanguageSpecific(String LanguageName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationFromCodeClass(CodeClass vsClass)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnNamespacePopulateTypes(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace.get_Types()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

The provided links on the page do not help since they only link to generic documentation/help pages. How can this error be fixed?

Comment: Does this exception occur if you copy and paste an existing form?

Comment: Does https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/issues/177 help?

Comment: @mjwills: Similar, see my answer below.

Comment: This is one of the frustrating and wide range error that might arise from VS messages to COM programming.

Answer (score 12):

I got this in Visual Studio 2019 in a Windows Forms app.  I'd been working on it for a few days, opening and closing the solution with no issue.  I applied a VS upgrade and when I went to open the app, I got this error message.

When nothing else worked, I unloaded and reloaded the project from the solution, and that fixed it.

I hope it's as simple as that for you.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the folder was named `Form` and that clashed with the [`Microsoft Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Renaming the inherited class from `Form` to `System.Windows.Forms.Form` twice in total fixes the issue. Still a bug that should be handled automatically like this by `Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 1):

Different Problem same Error Message SOLVED ... "Value does not fall within the expected range" and designer not displaying my form.

SOLUTION: I had docked-to-Fill with a control to my main form, and it worked fine. But then I started getting the error, and the "designer" no longer displayed.
I recently added a control from the Tool dialog with a double-click, instead of drag-and-drop ... that was the culprit.  To fix it, I commented the line (in the myFormMain.Designer.cs) that docked the control to the main form. And yes, the designer view worked again and I could find and delete the control I added from the Tools dialog with a double-click.